# Python giving me two different results while performing the same operation on the same objects twice

Tags: python

I created a class `vector2D` in python with a method to add vectors. Then I used it to add the same vectors twice and got different results. Why did that happen?

Here's the code:

```
class vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self.x, self.y   

#Creating vector objects
v1 = vector2D(2, 3)
v2 = vector2D(4, 8)

#using the redefined addition operator to add vector objects
v = v1 + v2       #output: (6, 11)
print(v)

#Adding again
v = v1 + v2      #output: (10, 19)
print(v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You both add the vectors in place and return the result!

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self.x, self.y
```

This changes first vector's parameters! `+=` means `self.x = self.x + other.x`.

Do this instead:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        result_x = self.x + other.x
        result_y = self.y + other.y
        return result_x, result_y
```

Answer (score 3):

Your doing `in place assignment`, when you do this

```
   self.x += other.x
```

you are changing the `x` attribute of the object it self, so when you do the second addition the `x` is changed.

One more thing `__add__` should return an instance of the same `class`, Developer when using your class they will expect when they add `vector2d` to another `vector2d` they get a `vector2d` but you are returning a `tuple`:

```
class vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

So when you add `vector2D + vector2D`  you get `vector2D` instance.